# Capistrano 3 - How to have deploy_to location in different stages

Tags: capistrano3

How do I set different deploy_to locations in my different stages.

If I put

```
:set :deploy_to, '/var/www/mywebsite'
```

in deploy.rb my app deploys successfully, but I want to have different deploy_to locations in production.rb and staging.rb, however if I move this line to the different files the app will not deploy, it uses the default deploy_to location of /var/www/my_app